# variable assignment syntax error

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm writing a program in python for a noughts and crosses game, using TKinter. I have create variables for each square's status and its location.

```
1ataken=0
1aROW=3
1aCOLUMN=1
```

(Capitals used to indicated constant).
However when I run this code, I come up with a syntax error on the first variable name (1ataken).
Any suggestions as to why this is happening?

Comment: In python, variable name can't start with a number. This link can be useful https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=13&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi4y_iO0tPVAhWMAcAKHQYVC1MQFgheMAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fthehelloworldprogram.com%2Fpython%2Fpython-variable-assignment-statements-rules-conventions-naming%2F&usg=AFQjCNH1-EuiR2AIerAPdO06qZYi1GBr5Q

Answer (score 1):

Simply, the name of a  variable must not start with a number in python. So you can for instance, name your variables like this:

> a_taken_1, a_row_1, and a_column_1

Or better:

> taken_1, row_1 and column_1